# Build failed in add firebase when added apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle

When i added this line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in `build.gradle(:app)` for add Firebase to my Android app , **i faced with this error and i did not find any log for solve it!!**

[image]

1-I added `google-services.json`

2-I added this  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'`

3-I added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

4-I added     `google()`

**Without this `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line app run without any problem and build success.**

**Build.gradle(module:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    //Retrofit2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1"

    //RxJava2
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.1'

    //Koin dependency injection
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:2.0.1"

    //PersistentCookieJar
    implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1'

    //Image loader
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    //MultiDex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'

    //Test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.0.0"
    testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1'
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

**Build.gradle(project):**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213752/discussion-on-question-by-milad-salimi-build-failed-in-add-firebase-when-added-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked everything and it seems okay, sometimes filenames and extensions are the issues:

1. Clean Project from Build menu inside Android Studio
2. Check your file name (Remove special characters or space if any available)
3. Rebuild your project

Hope it helps ;)